# Is there an economic analysis calculating the global cost benefits of veganism?

Tags: veganism, health, public-health

Are there any economic analyses that estimate the amount of money that would be saved if there was a massive shift from current diets to a vegan diet?

We know that [high-grain vegetarian diets can be over one-third (34%) cheaper](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lanplh/article/PIIS2542-5196(21)00251-5/fulltext) than "current diets" (and that vegan diets, generally, are found to be cheaper than vegetarian diets).

...But I'm not just asking about the cost benefits on an individual level. We know, for example, that there are massive costs associated with eating meat because of the detrimental health impacts (eg cardiometabolic diseases) as well as detrimental climate impacts (deforestation, methane emissions, etc).

Obviously, the tax burden to address [health issues](https://cpr.heart.org/-/media/Files/About-Us/Policy-Research/Fact-Sheets/Public-Health-Advocacy-and-Research/CVD-A-Costly-Burden-for-America-Projections-Through-2035.pdf) and the [climate catastrophe](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-023-41888-1) are significant. Indeed, these costs [have been quantified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_analysis_of_climate_change#Estimates) by scientific health and climate journals.

My question is: has there been any scientific literature published that has attempted to calculate **the total sum of expenses that would be saved** by either some region (eg a specific country) or the whole world **if a significant amount of people** in the region **shifted to a vegan diet**?

Comment: See also [Is eating vegan expensive?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/is-eating-vegan-expensive)

Comment: Please **re-open this question**. It's not subjective. In fact, a [study published in The Lancet Planetary Health (October 2021)](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lanplh/article/PIIS2542-5196(21)00251-5/fulltext) found that **high-grain vegetarian diets can be over one-third (34%) cheaper than "current diets"** and that vegan diets, generally, were cheaper than vegetarian diets.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield the question has been reopened - please feel free to post an answer