# Alternative to legumes when composing vegan daily menu

Tags: veganism, protein, diet, beans

What is the alternative to the legumes when composing vegan daily menu?

The assumptions are, that you need to provide full mix of exogenous amino acids every 24 h to prevent muscle decrease (correct me if I'm misinformed on that points), and that cereals are easily available and provide no digestion problems, so they can be always added to the menu.

Legumes need longer preparation and are not always practical (and consumed daily, a bit hard on digestion system).

Answer (score 2):

That's a tough one. Legumes are so versatile and such a great source of protein!

You say

> Legumes need longer preparation and are not always practical (and consumed daily, a bit hard on digestion system).

But, I would argue, some legumes are quite easy to prepare and eat.

Peanut butter, for example, is just right there in the jar :)

Tofu can be eaten with minimal preparation, or, occasionally, by me, with none.

Hummus - straight from the fridge onto your sandwich.

Beans and lentils are often available canned and cooked - ready to drop into a stew or just reheat and eat.

Fresh or frozen young green peas or edamame (baby soy beans) can be steam cooked in minutes.

Gram flour can be easily made into pancakes, farinata, bhajis or pakoras.

Legumes are sometimes made into pasta (though this can be expensive and is not available everywhere) and that cooks in about the same time as ordinary pasta made from semolina.

Even dry lentils, especially split and/or skinned, require relatively little preparation. For example, split skinned green gram (moong dal) can be consumed raw after an hour of soaking and a good rinse, or if not soaked, it can be thoroughly cooked in about 15 minutes (or less with a pressure cooker).

As for actual alternatives; all foods contain protein in some amount, including cereals. Seitan, for example, is made from wheat protein (gluten). These cereal proteins can also be hard on the digestive system for some people, though.

Some non-legume foods that have decent amounts of protein:

- seeds such as hemp, pumpkin and sunflower
- tree nuts such as almonds, walnuts, pecans
- grains such as quinoa, wheat, oats
- cooked mushrooms, potatoes, green veg

Comment: Hummus, beans, tofu, and lentils are all legumes. I think the OP is trying to avoid legumes. This is important for folks who are allergic to legumes. I've once made dal for such a person -- it was basically a soup with indian spices thickened with a roux. But if OP doesn't *actually* need to avoid legumes, then of course they can just be bought canned. Or cook a big pot once a month and can them yourself (eg in old glass pickle, pepper, or peanut butter jars)

Comment: @MichaelAltfield OP explains that they wish to avoid legumes due to "longer preparation", thus I contended that some leguminous foods do not require long preparation. This might help the OP. I agree that other visitors may need actual alternatives to legumes (I did mention some of those too).

Answer (score 1):

Almost all [fruits and vegetables have protein](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/10/can-you-achieve-sufficient-daily-complete-proteins-as-a-vegan-if-you-only-eat-gr).

While legumes and grains have especially high amounts of protein, some folks do have legume allergies. Most people's protein requirements can easily be met by just [eating a variety of whole foods](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/is-eating-vegan-expensive/2557#2557).

But if you want to *exceed* your nutritional requirements for protein (eg if you're a body builder), here's some legume-free, high-protein options:

### Seitan

[Seitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seitan) is made from wheat gluten, which is mostly protein at [75g of protein per 100g](https://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/cereal-grains-and-pasta/7738/2).

| [image: photo of a dish of vegan seitan schnitzel (source Einladung_zum_Essen via pixabay)] |
| --- |
| Vegan seitan schnitzel (source [Einladung_zum_Essen](https://pixabay.com/users/einladung_zum_essen-3625323/)) |

Seitan is very cheap [to make](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-is-seitan-how-do-i-get-it/58#58) and can be used as a high-protein meat substitute in almost anything.

### Nuts & Seeds

Nuts and seeds are very high in protein. Pumpkin seeds, for example, have 25g of protein per 100g serving.

[image: image of various squash seeds at a market, including pumpkin seeds]

### Tahini

[Tahini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahini) is a middle eastern condiment made from sesame seeds. It's a great alternative to hummus if you can't eat legumes.

| [image: photo of tahini and debes] |
| --- |
| Tahini (left) and [debes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_honey) (source [yilmazfatih](https://pixabay.com/users/yilmazfatih-7654055/)) |

Tahini has [59g of protein per 100g serving](https://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3142/2).

### Seaweed

Seaweed is very high in protein. Spirulina has 57g of protein per 100g.

### Mushrooms

Mushrooms are fairly high in protein. Shiitake, for example, has [10g of protein per 100g](https://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/vegetables-and-vegetable-products/2487/2).

### Grains

[Kamut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khorasan_wheat) and [Spaghetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasta) both have 6g of protein per 100g cooked.

Other grains have a fair amount of protein too. Each of these has 4g of protein per 100g, when cooked:

1. Oats
2. Quinoa
3. Teff
4. Amaranth
5. Couscous