# does hummus have sufficient methionine?

Tags: nutrition, food, protein

It looks like the limiting amino acid for hummus is methionine.

Hummus is mostly chickpeas, but also includes sesame (tahini), which is fairly plentiful in methionine.

Does store-bought hummus typically have sufficient methionine to make an appropriate mix of amino acids? Or would it be better to add *more* sesame seeds?

Comment: See also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/does-any-combination-of-a-cereal-and-a-legume-provide-the-complete-range-of-amin/2672#2672

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Protein requirements are [so easy to satisfy](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/151/4031) that you don't need to worry about it.

Before I learned about the now-debunked [myth of combining proteins](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/62/4031) from the 1950s, I did calculate the [precise ratio of garbanzo beans to tahini](https://green.michaelaltfield.net/2014/10/20/complete-protein-ratios/) to combine to unnecessarily maximize the absorption of all amino acids. I found that the ideal ratio was

> **1 tablespoon of tahini per 1 cup of cooked garbanzo beans**
>
> *Source https://green.michaelaltfield.net/2014/10/20/complete-protein-ratios/*

...which is roughly what's called-for in the average hummus recipe.

But if you're not looking to *exceed* your daily protein requirements (ie if you're not a body builder), then you can stop worrying about sourcing protein and just make sure to [eat a variety of whole foods](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/2557/4031).

Comment: Thanks. Not a body builder but I am trying to gain muscle and hopefully lose some fat at the same time, so I think this is relevant to me.